# MathJaX Bugs - `Show Math As ->TeX Commands` and Bold Math in comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

I am using `Chrome 18.0.1025.142` on a Windows 7 machine. There are two recent behaviours of MathJaX I have observed:

1. We may want to see the TeX commands for some of the math we see on the main site. It is usually done by `Show Math as -> TeX commands`. But when I used to do this before, it comes up as a small screen and it looked good. But,now, it opens in a new window but not small, as it used to. I need to open that as a tab or maximize that window every time to see those commands.$^\dagger$
2. The math in the comments appear in a darker shade than they used to. Is that a new "feature" or an undesirable behaviour? Personally, I classify that as the latter.

---

$\dagger$ [Antonio Vargas](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/5531/antonio-vargas) confirmed this bug in chrome, the same version, at the Math chat room. The user [robjohn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13854/robjohn) confirms that this works fine on Firefox 11.0 for Mac (OS X 10.5.8).

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this bug, at least #1 (though now that I look again math in comments does seem a bit darker).  I was talking to Kannappan in chat and I mentioned that everything was working fine for me with Chrome 17.0.963.83m.  However, upon loading the "about" window, Chrome automatically updated to 18.0.1025.142 and I immediately experienced error #1 described.  If I right-click and select Show Math as -> TeX commands, the small window loads but is invisible and apparently inaccessible.

Comment: Thanks for confirming and perhaps describing better. Yes, it is apparently _inaccessible_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like Chrome 18 has changed how it handles allowing javascript to resize a window (there are security issues with this), and so MathJax's window no longer opens properly. I'm looking into it to see what can be done.

Comment: Sure. No worries. :-)

Comment: I'll accept this as an answer because I know we'll hear from you soon.

Comment: It looks like it is [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=115585), and that it may already be fixed in Chrome 19.  I'll still look at fixing it, but may not have a new version out before Chrome 19 appears.

Comment: Oh, I see. I am not savvy enough to understand the issues but still will appreciate a fix. Regards,